# Retrieve/list all entries with active timestamps before today

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, search, timestamped

Is there a way to list all agenda entries which have active timestamps state (no DEADLINE or SCHEDULED)? I ask because these get lost in the agenda unlike Deadlines and Scheduled tasks, which keep being reminded. I often mark tasks just with timestamps and some of them are unacted upon and left in the past. The only way to check for them is to browse the agenda week by week. I hope I made myself clear here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tag/property matches:

1. run `M-x org-agenda m` and enter `TIMESTAMP<"<today>"`
2. or use a `org-agenda-custom-command`

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("t" "Timestamp Before today"
         ((tags "TIMESTAMP<\"<today>\"")))))
```

For more details, please refer `Matching tags and properties` section of Org Manual:

1. `M-x info-display-manual` (`C-h R`)
2. enter and select `org`
3. `M-x Info-menu` (`m`)
4. enter and select `Matching tags and properties`

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed! note: I think one pair of brackets is not necessary -> ("t". note2: (2) works but (1) doesn't in my system: I run M-x org-agenda m and enter TIMESTAMPS<"<today>" and only shows me one entry weirdly.

Comment: Hi, 1) the outside pair of brackets if necessary if you have multi agenda custom commands, the default value of `org-agenda-custom-commands`  also have it. 2) both work for me on my side, there is not 's' after `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Thanks for all answers. It works now. Is it possible to add the condition to exclude all DONE and CANCELLED items?

Comment: Yes, the manual has detailed instructions, you can find the example there. 'TIMESTAMP<"<today>"/!-DONE-CANCELLED'

Comment: In which section is this info specifically? Thanks!

Comment: I have mentioned in this answer.

Comment: Thanks, my bad!

Comment: One problem: If I do `TIMESTAMP<"<today>"` I get all timestamped entries before today (all: DONE, TODO, without TODO status, etc.). When I do `TIMESTAMP<"<today>"/!-DONE`, I not only exclude `DONE` but also any other tasks that have status (those who are only timestamped without any selected status). I would like to see these timestamped entries too.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein Hi, I answer you at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70572/how-to-show-timestamped-entries-without-todo-status/70578#70578