# How to show timestamped entries without TODO status

Tags: org-agenda, search, todo, filtering

I understand from the manual that the command for doing a search of agenda entries which have a timestamp before today is as follows:

```
TIMESTAMP<"<today>"
```

If I additionally want to remove from that search `DONE` items, I must do:

```
TIMESTAMP<"<today>"/!-DONE
```

However, this search only returns timestamped items WITH a `TODO` status except the `DONE` status, while leaving out all the timestamped entries without any status. Is is possible to retrieve these too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `+TIMESTAMP<"<today>"-TODO="DONE"`

Comment: Thank you! How would I add more TODO statuses? For instance, if I want to exclude not only DONE items but also CANCELED and NOT ATTENDED items?

Comment: `+TIMESTAMP<"<today>"-TODO="DONE"-TODO="CANCELED"` (I'm not sure what NOT ATTENDED is, you can check section Special Properties in org manual whether something matches)

Comment: Thanks. It seems one can use "Not ATTENDED" with space. However, how to write this for org-agenda-custom-commands? `(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands `("T" "Timestamp Before today"  '((tags "TIMESTAMP<\"<today>\""-TODO="DONE"-TODO="CANCELED"-TODO="NOT ATTENDED\ "))))` does not work. Not sure where to use back slashes.

Comment: Just before `"`, try `(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands '("T" "Timestamp Before today" ((tags "TIMESTAMP<\"<today>\"-TODO=\"DONE\"-TODO=\"CANCELED\"-TODO=\"NOT ATTENDED\""))))`

Comment: You should not ask additional questions in a comment: there is no way to seach to find answers to such questions (even if they are asnwered).  Some people modify a question after it is answered: you should not do that either. If the answer has answered your question, accept it (as you did), optionally mark it as useful by clicking the up arrow and that's that. If you have an additional question, *ask a new question*, possibly referring back to this one for context. That way, crisp questions have crisp answers that will be useful to others in the future.

Comment: Thanks, point taken.